# Factory's claims and passing it arguments to initialize objects it creates

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory

Factory pattern brings two main things to the table:

- Detaches client side code from exact implementation details of classes.
- Centralize code creation so if the creation logic changes, it is changed only in the factory instead of possible 20 files.

But what if I want to pass specific arguments to the constructor to initialize it properly? This would come from user or current state of the application. Wouldn't this kind of defeat the 2nd point?

```
class AnimalFactory
{
public:
    createAnimal(type, string nickName)
    {
        if (type == 0)
            return new Dog(nickName);
        else if(type == 1)
            return new Cat(nickName);
    }
}
```

The above is how I have seen in examples, but is the following equally good factory, perhaps even more preferable since its more readable and pass one less argument?

```
class AnimalFactory
{
public:
    createDog(string nickName)
    {
        return new Dog(nickName);
    }

    createCat(string nickName)
    {
        return new Cat(nickName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on usage.

Anyway, in the second version I do not see benefits from just calling  a constructor directly.
Seems like the only good thing about it is ability to put this functions into the `map`.

In the first version the map can be an implementation detail of the facory method.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the Factory Pattern is hiding volatile things when creating objects by exposing a stable interface. Both of your two factories hide the types `Dog` & `Cat`, and expose the abstract type `Animal`. This is good.

The 2nd factory is more readable but what if its interface is changed? For example, when you add a new method `createElephant`, some of your client code which don't care about `Elephant` still needs to be recompiled and redeployed. In such a situation, the 1st factory is better although it is less readable.

So, the choosing of the factory depends on how likely your code changes. Just remember to keep the factory interface stable.

Comment: Well this is argument that I don't understand. If I have to create new `Elephant` type, I will have to create a new 'type` which will be passed to factory to create it anyways, so the code does changes!? If that is not enough, imagine for elephant I need to pass the `herd name` as well that it belongs..that requires code change as well. This is why I am not able to fully appreciate this aspect of factory as advantage.

Comment: Thing is, the signature of the interface of the factory changes. This makes some clients of the factory be affected unnecessarily because they never want to createElephant. By "affected" I mean recompiled and redeployed, not source code of the clients change. Indeed, those code don't change :)